# Filtering SQL Server rows based on timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, filtering, where-clause

I have a query that is based on timestamp.

Sometimes my update through a SQL Server stored procedure hits twice within the same second thus producing identical rows with timestamps only differing a few seconds. Any idea how to create a `WHERE` clause that filters out rows where the timestamp distance with its above row are less than a minute? Thanks.

[image]

| timestamp | item bought |
| --- | --- |
| 3/15/2021 3:08:43 PM | Grape |
| 3/15/2021 3:30:58 PM | Apple |
| 3/15/2021 3:30:59 PM | Apple |
| 3/15/2021 3:50:29 PM | Passionfruit |
| 3/15/2021 4:29:47 PM | Orange |

This is the current database I am working with. I'd like to filter out the section where it was shown duplicates of Apple within same second. I am currently also working to alter the stored procedure, but in the meantime can I filter out the query result so it may look like this?

| timestamp | item bought |
| --- | --- |
| 3/15/2021 3:08:43 PM | Grape |
| 3/15/2021 3:30:58 PM | Apple |
| 3/15/2021 3:50:29 PM | Passionfruit |
| 3/15/2021 4:29:47 PM | Orange |

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t*
from (select t.*,
             lag(timetamp) over (partition by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where t.timestamp < dateadd(second, 60, prev_timestamp ) or
      prev_timestamp is null;
```

Comment: thanks for responding quickly, i am using MS SQL.